# text-align on a table in a cell (<table> inside a <td>)

Tags: css, html-table, alignment, cell

Here's something I never thought I'd say: I have a problem in Firefox and Chrome, but it's working fine in IE!

It's very simple, but I don't understand why it doesn't work:

I have a table inside a cell, and I have `style="text-align:right"` on the cell, but the table is staying left in Firefox and Chrome (in IE it's obediently going to the right...). If I put align=right in the cell tag then it works, but I don't want to do that.

Code is basically:

```
<table width="1000" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:right">

      <table border="1">
        <tr><td>Hello</td><td>Hello 2</td></tr>
      </table>

    </td>

    <td>Hello 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I don't want the nested table to be width=100% or anything like that...

Could anyone please explain to me why it doesn't work, and how to fix it, and maybe why it works in IE but not Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: I think it's correct in FF and Chrome.  The table is not text, so text-align should not affect it. align should work on any content.

Comment: Thanks - so how would I use css to align the table in the cell? Is this new? I've got back into website making after a couple of years, and I never had this problem before?

Comment: Text-align affects inline & inline-block elements, not just text.

Comment: add to your nested table display property and set it to inline-block <table border="1" style="display:inline-block">

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is that Chrome and FF are actually the ones rendering it correctly. `text-align` probably isn't supposed to affect `table` elements. However, applying `float:right` to the table will do what you want.

Comment: Thank you all so much! Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to add that the CSS way to align tables relative to its container is with the margin property.

You must add `margin: 0 auto;` if you'd like to align it to the center, or `margin-left: auto;` if you'd like to align it to the right.

As @maxedison says, `text-align` will work only with `inline` and `inline-block` elements, so the other solution is change your inner table to take some of those display values.

You also need to remember that `text-align` works from 'container-to-content', this means it is normally applied to a container to affect its content (applied to a `p` to affect its inline content such as the text within), and `margin: 0 auto` works from 'content-to-container', meaning that it's normally applied to a block element and affects its position related to its container (applied to a `div` to center it to its parent).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fix it (not with full functionality), you can write this:

```
table {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This makes your table able to be centered with `text-align: center;`, if applied to the parent element(s).

Answer (score 0):

when you don't want the div to be floating, you may try this :
http://jsfiddle.net/NvEZ8/

```
<div style="text-align:right;">
   <table  style="display:inline-block">
       <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td></td>
           <td>one</td>
           <td>two</td>
       </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

It looks like text-align (with a DOCTYPE html) only affects inline-block in Chrome and not inline only element. Replacing inline-block by inline here and it doesn't work anymore on my Chrome